# Is it possible to use parse.com pointers with images across classes using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, parse-platform

Using parse.com and the Javascript SDK.

I've an image stored in my "_User" class.

I have a class called "links"

Each user will have multiple records stored in the links class.

When querying the links class I want to be able to access the image stored against the user.

Do I use a pointer of relationship for this? or do I achieve this using a query?

Just looking for some direction, maybe a code example if available.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Each user has Many rows in 'Links' "

"Image store in _User"

Sounds like you should have the same pointer-to-user-image value available on 2 access paths.

1. Getting _User includes link to the file that is image of the user.
2. Getting the Links rows for a user ( includes some independent link to same image )

Note that your logged in user will always have a ref to the _User so anytime you are logged in you have reference to the img-link for logged in user.

Note that if you are logged on as "A" and you query _User(B) rows in 'Links' ( assuming you have access to them ) then you also have to pointer to User A's image in the results.

If those 2 , independent access paths what you want then just provide the same pointer in both classes ( _User, Links ).

Comment: I'll mark this as answered, it kinda helped...but really lead me to this question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23713134/how-to-access-returned-objects-from-query-so-that-images-can-be-displayed