# How to access returned objects from query so that images can be displayed?

Tags: javascript, parse-platform

Parse.com and JavaScript.

The code below is returning the correct results, as per the screen shots, but..

How can I return and access each of the objects that has been captured by this query? I want to use the "pic" column which is held within the _User class. At the moment my images are returning undefined.

```
    var currentUser = Parse.User.current();  
var FriendRequest = Parse.Object.extend("FriendRequest");


    var query = new Parse.Query(FriendRequest);
    query.equalTo("fromUser", currentUser);
    query.equalTo("status", "Request sent");
    //query.exists("pic");
         query.find({
              success: function(results) {
        // If the query is successful, store each image URL in an array of image URL's
        imageURLs = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) { 
          var object = results[i];
          imageURLs.push(object.get('pic'));
        }
     // If the imageURLs array has items in it, set the src of an IMG element to the first URL in the array
        for(var j = 0; j < imageURLs.length; j++){
            $('#imgs').append("<img src='" + imageURLs[j] + "'/>");                 
        }
      },
      error: function(error) {
        // If the query is unsuccessful, report any errors
        alert("Error: " + error.code + " " + error.message);
      }
    });
         // show the signup or login page

 </script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if the images are stored in an relation array "pic" which is an element in "FriendRequest" then you have to do an additional RELATION query to retrieve the array ....

```
this.collection = new UserList();
this.model = this.options.model;  // check whether user or role shoul b user        
var relation = this.model.relation("users");
this.collection.query = relation.query();       
var role = this.model.id;
var rolename = this.model.get("name");
this.collection.fetch();
```

Above module works with Parse._Roles which has "users" field - an array of type relation

To work with the relation pointers in "user" , a 'relation' query is required. After the fetch, in the collection, you have the array of pointers like you want for your images.

Comment: Thanks, I've also found out by adding query.include('toUser'); below var query = new Parse.Query(FriendRequest); this brings back the whole object, which includes the "pic" url. This seems an alternative method to get the data?

Comment: I dont supose you could help me solve this ?! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23714195/why-wont-this-return-the-image-from-an-object-to-display-the-image-in-html