# Why wont this return the image from an object to display the image in html?

Tags: javascript, parse-platform

UPDATED WITH CODE & IMAGE

It looks like the images for each of the returned objects in the query are "undefined"

Parse.com and JavaScript.

I've managed to get my code to return the object I want, now I just want to take out the "pic" url so that I can show it on the html page.

I've looked, but struggle to see examples of how to pull out certain attributes of a class.

The below shows my approach, but thats returning a bad url as shown in the screen shot.

What have I done wrong here?

```
    var currentUser = Parse.User.current();  
var FriendRequest = Parse.Object.extend("FriendRequest");


    var query = new Parse.Query(FriendRequest);
    query.include('toUser');
    query.equalTo("fromUser", currentUser);
    query.equalTo("status", "Request sent");
    //query.exists("pic");
         query.find({
              success: function(results) {
        // If the query is successful, store each image URL in an array of image URL's
        imageURLs = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) { 
          var object = results[i];
          imageURLs.push(object.get('pic'));
        }
     // If the imageURLs array has items in it, set the src of an IMG element to the first URL in the array
        for(var j = 0; j < imageURLs.length; j++){
            $('#imgs').append("<img src='" + imageURLs[j] + "'/>");                 
        }
      },
      error: function(error) {
        // If the query is unsuccessful, report any errors
        alert("Error: " + error.code + " " + error.message);
      }
    });
         // show the signup or login page

 </script>
<div id="imgs"></div>
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: `results[0].toUser.pic`

Comment: If you add the full code in the answer I can accept, thanks

Comment: Please post a) code b) JSON c) no pictures

Comment: @Bergi sorry, I have added the code now

Comment: you are not accessing the objects correctly.
bad -   results[0].toUser.pic   

try - results[0].get("toUser").pic   or some expression reflecting how you actually traverse the embedded stuff in your response from the network get.

Comment: @RobertRowntree ok thanks! if you want to add the answer I will accept and close the question.

Comment: @RobertRowntree sorry also noticed that query.include('toUser'); was missing from the above code. Which I have now added, not sure if that makes a difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Descend the stack using "get()" where you have an object as in :

results[0].get("toUser").pic

instead of :

results[0].toUser.pic

In your pic of the debugger, the type of results.0.toUser is "Object".

I dont think you will get a good reference to an object without using the javascript

.get(myObject)

Since you are not using a framework (setting collection and model that make it very easy ) that encapsulates all the specifics of parseing the response , you will have to do it by hand , making sure that each step you descend is done so you have a valid reference/type to what is the child.

The reason you have undefined for results.0.toUser.pic is that you've not done the parse correctly.

Comment: I'm really sorry to be a complete pain in the arse, but I'm not sure I'm updating the code correctly could you give me an actual example of the code block? sorry to take up your time

Comment: based on what you said, is this code correct? http://jsfiddle.net/DneT4/ if it is, I still dont seem to be getting undefined images back.... cheers

Comment: 'Parse' undef in you fiddle . you need to add the parse lib in the upper left of the fiddle

Comment: http://marionette-todo.parseapp.com/   why dont you play with this app. debug it . find the source.  learn a good framework (parse/backbone/marionette)...

Comment: you will be happy to know I have now resolved this! Its only taken all weekend! Thanks for the help!